# How to find the Euler-Lagrange Equation for a function that has higher order derivatives with multiple variables?

Tags: integration, optimization, partial-derivative, calculus-of-variations

If we're trying to extremize the functional, $I = \int\int f(u) dx dy$ , where: $$f(u) = u^2 + (\frac{\partial u}{\partial x})^2 + (\frac{\partial u}{\partial y})^2 + (\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2})^2 + (\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x \partial y})^2+ (\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2})^2$$

As far as my understanding goes, for a functional with higher order derivatives, then the E-L function would be something like: $$(\frac{\partial F}{\partial u}) - \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}(\frac{\partial F}{\partial u_x}) - \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}y}(\frac{\partial F}{\partial u_y})+ \frac{\mathrm{d^2}}{\mathrm{d}x^2}(\frac{\partial F}{\partial u_{xx}}) + \frac{\mathrm{d^2}}{\mathrm{d}y^2}(\frac{\partial F}{\partial u_{yy}})$$

However, I'm not sure about what to do with the partial derivative with respect to both $x$ and $y$. Thus far, I've found that: $$\frac{\partial F}{\partial u} = 2u, \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}(\frac{\partial F}{\partial u_x}) = 2u_{xx}, \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}y}(\frac{\partial F}{\partial u_y}) = 2u_{yy}, \frac{\mathrm{d^2}}{\mathrm{d}x^2}(\frac{\partial F}{\partial u_{xx}}) = 2u_{xxxx}, \frac{\mathrm{d^2}}{\mathrm{d}y^2}(\frac{\partial F}{\partial u_{yy}}) = 2u_{yyyy}$$If anyone could help and could point out any mistakes I've made thus far, that would be much appreciated.

Comment: You [missed the cross term](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Lagrange_equation#Single_function_of_two_variables_with_higher_derivatives) in the expression after 'the E-L function would be something like'. And they should be partial derivatives in that expression, not total derivatives. Apart from those two issues, your calculation after 'Thus far, I've found that' looks correct.

Comment: @mattos Could you elaborate on what is meant by "cross term"? I'm not quite sure what I'm supposed to be looking at on the Wikipedia page. Also, it would appear that the term I'm looking for would just $2u_{xyxy}$ is that right?

Comment: Yes, the term you are missing is $2u_{xyxy}$. In your notation, the cross term you missed in $f(u)$ was the $$\frac{\partial F}{\partial u_{x y}}$$ term, which you then needed to differentiate for the ELE $$\frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial x \partial y} \left( \frac{\partial F}{\partial u_{x y}} \right) = 2u_{x y x y} = 2u_{xxyy}$$ as you have stated in your comment. Now that you have computed the derivative of the cross term it seems you have accounted for all terms in the ELE and so now you can form the ELE explicitly by taking the required linear combination.

Comment: Go back to first principles. Integrating by parts,$$\begin{align}\delta I&=\iint\left(f_u\delta u+f_{u_x}\delta u_x+f_{u_y}\delta u_y+f_{u_{xx}}\delta u_{xx}+f_{u_{xy}}\delta u_{xy}+f_{u_{yy}}\delta u_{yy}\right)dxdy\\&=\iint\left(f_u-f_{u_xx}-f_{u_yy}+f_{u_{xx}xx}+f_{u_{xy}xy}+f_{u_{yy}yy}\right)\delta udxdy\\\implies0&=f_u-f_{u_xx}-f_{u_yy}+f_{u_{xx}xx}+f_{u_{xy}xy}+f_{u_{yy}yy}.\end{align}$$I'm not sure why @mattos says a factor of $2$ should appear; maybe my original integrand should also include $f_{u_{yx}}\delta u_{yx}$.

Comment: @J.G. Each term in $f(u)$ is quadratic in form and so differentiating each individual term as the OP has done yields a factor of $2$. Your approach also has these factors of $2$, they are just hidden in the notation you have used i.e $$f_{u} = 2u, \quad f_{u_{x,y}xy} = (2u_{xy})_{x,y} = 2u_{xxyy}$$ These factors can all then be divided out once you write out the ELE explicitly with RHS equal to $0$.

Comment: @mattos Of course! Thanks.